# Non-linear, hyperbolic, 2nd order system of PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-operators, classical-mechanics, hyperbolic-pde

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262312/non-linear-system-of-hyperbolic-pdes).

In the context of two dimensional elasticity theory, when considering deformations of flat membranes into spherical caps, one encounters the following hyperbolic system

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial y}\right)&=K\:\alpha\beta\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}\right)&=-K\:\alpha\beta,
\end{align}

with $K$ a fixed, real, positive constant. We typically set Goursat data along the axes consisting of $\alpha(x,0)$ and $\beta(0,y)$, so the first question is

> Does there exist a unique solution? (At least on points sufficiently close to the initial lines)

(moreover, there should be no reason to restrict $K$ to be a constant, but the same answer may apply if it's a smooth function.)

Setting aside the initial conditions, is it possible to write down some analytic solutions with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ other than polynomials?

Comment: Any chance you’d be interested in setting the initial data along the line $y=x$ or any other line but the axes?

Comment: @DeaneYang Thank you. Non-characteristic lines are not our primary focus, but any suggestions even in that case would be helpful.

Comment: It was just a hopeful but not really serious question. The noncharacteristic initial value problem is well-posed, and there exists a unique solution in a neighborhood of the line. It also seems possible that if the initial data is sufficiently small, a globl solution exists.

Comment: Are you sure you are giving enough initial data? For a system like this, usually local existence and uniqueness is independent of lower order perturbations. So consider the simplified equation where $K = 0$. Suppose $\alpha(x,0) = a_0$ and $\beta(0,y) = b_0$, then any pair of linear functions of the form $\alpha(x,y) = a_0 + \gamma y$ and $\beta(x,y) = \beta_0 + \delta x$ would solve the system. I expect similar counter examples can be found after restoring $K > 0$.

Comment: Ignoring convergence issues, just thinking about the solvability of the power series expansion near the origin, it seems to me you need to also prescribe at least $\partial_y \alpha (x,0)$ and $\partial_x \beta(0,y)$ to have a chance of guaranteeing that the solution you write down is unique.

Comment: Daniel, just for the sake of correctness, It would be advisable to add a remark to point out that you have already asked [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262312/non-linear-system-of-hyperbolic-pdes) several days ago and no one has answered.

Comment: What is Gouraat data?